# Regex: Include specific expression in the search

Tags: regex

I have the following string:

```
CHECKING % x j1 (test1^3) @ phi=0 j2 (test2/3) @ phi=1 j3 @ phi=2 j1 (test1^3) @ phi=2 j2 (test2/3) @ phi=3 j3 @ phi=5
CHECKING % x ab (test1^3) @ phi=0 cde (test2/3) @ phi=1 fg @ phi=2 hij (test1^3) @ phi=2 kl (test2/3) @ phi=3 mn @ phi=5
```

I would like to get all the `j1`, `j2` and `j3` as well as the `ab`, `cde` ... so everything in front of the brackets or the `@` sign respectively, but somehow I cannot make it work. Does someone have an idea for a regex?

Here is what I have tried:

`([a-zA-Z_]+[0-9]{0,4})\s+\(.{0,9}\)\s+\@`

which gives:

`j1 j2 j1 j2 ... ab cde hij kl`

But it does not match the `j3`, `fg` and `mn`, how can I include the `(...)` term only if appearing?

Comment: Do you want the `j_n` or do you want the values in parenthesis?

Comment: I want the `j_n`

Comment: Then just use [`j\d+`](https://regex101.com/r/jNHgAK/1)

Comment: Sorry my question was unclear, let me re-ask it

Comment: If you want the `j` and whatever is in parenthesis if there is one, use [`(j\d+)(?:\s)(\(.*?\))?`](https://regex101.com/r/jNHgAK/2)

Comment: @chrisz thanks but that does not match the `j3`

Comment: Yes it does check the link.

Comment: Works, can you modify it to also match the `ab`, `cde`, `fg`,... and post it as an answer, then I can accept it, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on your original pattern, you can make the part in brackets optional to capture cases without a formula:

```
([a-zA-Z_]+[0-9]{0,4})\s+(?:\(.{0,9}\))?\s*\@
```

[**Demo**](https://regex101.com/r/7m9d6d/1)

Comment: Awesome, exactly this optional thing I was looking for. So the (?:Something) makes Something optional? What does the ? after the brackets do?

Comment: (?:) is a [non-capturing group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/what-is-a-non-capturing-group-what-does-do). The crucial part, however, is the `?` mark after the group, which makes it optional. Also note the following whitespace `\s*`which has a star quantifier (zero or more times), and therefore also optional.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative would be:

[`\w+(?= \()|\w+(?= @)`](https://regex101.com/r/7m9d6d/2)

This looks for words followed by `\s(` or followed by `\s@`.